# Gitlab pipeline image with AWSCLI and Git

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Hi I currently have this code in my pipeline:

```
stages:
  - api-init  
  - api-plan
  - api-apply

run-api-init:
  stage: api-init
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/aws-base:latest
  script:
    - git submodule add --name $rnme ../test.git
    - aws s3 cp xxx xxx
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: build.env
```

But I am getting the error:

```
> /usr/bin/bash: line 127: git: command not found
```

as my image does not have git command inside.

Is there any image I can use that has both awscli and git command?